# what are the properties of gamma function?

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions, gamma-function

In mathematics, the gamma function (represented by the capital Greek letter $\Gamma$) is an extension of the factorial function,
example:
 $\Gamma(x)$,  $\Gamma(ix)$.

What are the physical properties of gamma function (string theories) ?

Comment: This might be a candidate for migration to Physics.SE?

Comment: What do you mean by the "physical properties" of a function?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews string is a physics theory!. isn't it?!

Comment: But what does that have to do with the gamma function? The gamma function is not a physical object, so it does not have physical properties.

Comment: " The gamma function is not a physical object, so it does not have physical properties. "

This should be the ultimate answer!

Answer (score 4):

"Physical" properties?  As in properties relevant to physics?  If that's what the question is about, I might be more explicit about that fact, and *then* maybe consider migration of physics.SE.

"The properties of the gamma function" is an extensive enough topic for a long and heavy book.  I'll mention only one here, and then maybe add more later if I feel like it.
$$
\Gamma(\alpha) = \int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,dx.
$$
Sometimes people ask: Why $\alpha-1$ instead of $\alpha$?  Here's one answer; there are probably others.  Consider the probability density function
$$
f_\alpha(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} & \text{for }x>0 \\[12pt] 0 & \text{for }x<0 \end{cases}
$$
The use of $\alpha-1$ instead of $\alpha$ makes the family $\{f_\alpha : \alpha > 0\}$ a "convolution semigroup":
$$
f_\alpha * f_\beta = f_{\alpha+\beta}\tag{1}
$$
where the asterisk represents convolution.

**Later note:** If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with respective densities $f_\alpha$ and $f_\beta$, then $f_\alpha*f_\beta$ is the density of the random variable $X+Y$.  So $(1)$ explains why the "shape parameters" of gamma densities simply add up the way they do.

Comment: *"The properties of the gamma function" is an extensive enough topic for a long and heavy book*. But, *please*, start with Artin's beautiful, short, skinny one if you're going to read one. :) Also, I strongly suspect Legendre was not thinking about gamma random variables when choosing his notation, though your remark is interesting. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't about "physical properties", but the [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr-Mollerup_theorem) characterizes the gamma function with simple properties:

> $\Gamma(x)$  is the only function $f: (0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ that satisfies $f(x+1)=xf(x)$ with $\log(f(x))$ convex and $f(1)=1$.